# VBScript saying "No Application is associated with the specified file for this operation"?

Tags: vbscript

I'm writing a simple VBScript to write to a custom windows event log using eventcreate.

```
FOR I = 0 to 5
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strCommand = "eventcreate /l Application /t Information /so Test-Log /id 66 /d TEST"
    WshShell.Run strCommand
Next
```

However, whenever I try to run it through the command prompt, I get the following message:

> C:\testlog.vbs(6, 5) (null): No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.

From what I can tell, I'm doing exactly what the online examples are telling me to do, I just can't seem to replicate it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your script and it worked as expected on a win 7 laptop. Ensure you are running the script with admin rights. I changed the script a little, I moved the `Set` statement out for the `For...Next` loop. There is no need to continue to set the `WshShell` object on each loop, setting it once for the entire script is fine in this instance.

```
Dim WshShell, strCommand 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For I = 0 to 5
    strCommand = "eventcreate /l Application /t Information /so Test-Log /id 66 /d TEST"
    WshShell.Run strCommand
Next
```

Comment: I don't know what happened.  I restarted the computer and then it worked fine.  Thanks for the answer!